# How to select only first matching value from another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my database schema:

Payment table:

```
+------------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| payment_id | tab_id | amount | created             |
+------------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| 1          | 1      |  5     | 2017-05-22 12:14:27 |
| 2          | 2      |  10    | 2017-05-22 12:15:21 |
| 3          | 2      |  1     | 2017-05-22 13:11:14 |
+------------+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

Tab table:

```
+------------+----------------+
| tab_id     | service_charge |
+------------+----------------+
| 1          | 1              |
| 2          | 3              |
+------------+----------------+
```

I need to calculate total amounts (`amount` + `service_charge`) per payment, but `service_charge` should be included only in first payment matching `tab_id`.

My current query:

```
SELECT
  payment.payment_id,
  (payment.amount + tab.service_charge) as total_amount,
  payment.created
FROM payment
  INNER JOIN tab
    ON payment.tab_id = tab.tab_id;
```

**Actual result:**
As you can see below `service_charge` from `tab_id = 2` included twice (`payment_id = 2` and `payment_id = 3`).

```
+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| payment_id | total_amount    | created             |
+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 1          | 6               | 2017-05-22 12:14:27 |
| 2          | 13              | 2017-05-22 12:15:21 |
| 3          | 4               | 2017-05-22 13:11:14 |
+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

**Expected result:**
`total_amount` should not include `service_charge` in `payment_id = 3` as shown below.

```
+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| payment_id | total_amount    | created             |
+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 1          | 6               | 2017-05-22 12:14:27 |
| 2          | 13              | 2017-05-22 12:15:21 |
| 3          | 1               | 2017-05-22 13:11:14 |
+------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I took a look, but it's still not clear to me how that topic can help me to solve the problem I have.

Comment: Read the accepted answer (that's been upvoted 106 times). Follow the simple instructions. And see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should determine which is the first payment matching the tab_id and then based on that info, decide if you want to use the service_charge or not:

```
SELECT
  payment.payment_id,
  payment.amount + if (payment.created=m.mintime, tab.service_charge, 0) as total_amount,
  payment.created
FROM payment
  INNER JOIN tab
    ON payment.tab_id = tab.tab_id
  JOIN (
    SELECT tab_id, min(created) as 'mintime'
    FROM payment
    GROUP BY tab_id
  ) AS m on m.tab_id = payment.tab_id;
```

Comment: Thanks. Simple and elegant.